# Is it possible to copy U1 files between two PCs locally when an Ubuntu user account is recreated?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, clipboard

I have 2 Ubuntu 11.04 PCs (desktop and laptop), both synced via U1. Recently I completely rebuilt the user account (completely deleted the home directory) on one of the two (the desktop), and now I have to resync. Problem is that the PC is on a slow connection and I have difficulties resyncing the 14gb of data. Of course I have the opportunity of moving it to a place where the connection is faster, but it's not comfortable, and it will take some time. Since the laptop is in sync with the account I was wondering if stopping the service and copying the files + some database (which files is the question) could let me avoid resyncing everything.....

Answer (score 2):

Yes, simply copy all of your laptop's files to an external flash/hard drive, then mount it on your desktop and transfer the data over that way. It is much faster, but then I'm not sure whether you would have such a drive handy.

Comment: This is exactly the way to do it. I do this even with a good connection. Backup machine 1's U1 files, copy them over to machine 2, then sign in to U1 on machine 2. By far the fastest solution.

Answer (score -1):

You could give [this](http://www.micahcarrick.com/unison-synchronize-ubuntu.html) a try.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.